# Max after group by with sum

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, max

I’m trying to get from this two tables customer and invoice this information: the total from invoice for every year for each country! So what I wrote is:

```
SELECT SUM(i.total) AS Total_invoice, strftime(‘%Y’, i.InvoiceDate) AS year, c.country
FROM invoice i JOIN
     customer c
     ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
GROUP BY 2,3
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

So I get the total of invoice for each year! Now if I want the max(total) for each country how do you do? For example I’d like to have for each country the max( total), the year and the country! Could you help? Tha k you very much [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48cGp.jpg)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

> For example I’d like to have for each country the max( total), the year and the country!

For this, use window functions:

```
SELECT yc.*
FROM (SELECT SUM(i.total) AS Total_invoice, strftime(‘%Y’, i.InvoiceDate) AS year, c.country,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.country ORDER BY SUM(i.total) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM invoice i JOIN
           customer c
           ON i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
      GROUP BY 2, 3
     ) yc
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: @Elicasi86 . . . If this answer works for you, then you should consider accepting it.